# How to extract activation from CNN layers using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, activation, conv-neural-network

I want to extract the neural activation from the Fully connected layers. In Caffe i was doing like this ***net.blobs[layer_name].data***

How can i do the same in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You should use session object to get values stored in tensors. Try not to forget to pass values of placeholder tensors as feed_dict.

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSesssion()

full_connected = ....
value_of_fully_connected = sess.run(fully_connected,feed_dict={your_placeholders_and_values)
```