# How to access the fully connected layer from pretrained models in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I have found the pretrained models from this link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models

I'm also using the `inception_resnet_v2` model for my task.

And I have loaded the architecture into memory and made some predictions. However, I want to access the fully connected layer through using a **session** like in this post:

[How to get the output of the fully connected layer from CNN in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131940/how-to-get-the-output-of-the-fully-connected-layer-from-cnn-in-tensorflow)

after accessing the layer, I want the output of the layer or the **CNN Activations**